# Image file not found

Tags: ocr, tesseract

Through `Homebrew`, I have installed the Tesseract OCR engine on my Mac. All the directories (`jpeg`, `leptonica`, `libpng`, `libtiff`, `openssl`, `tesseract`) are now installed in `/usr/local/Cellar`

Before putting an image in the `Cellar` directory, when I try the following at the command line, **obviously** it fails:

```
$ tesseract image.png outcome
```

So, because there is no such image, I get the following error messages:

```
Error in fopenReadStream: file not found
Error in findFileFormat: image file not found
Error during processing.
```

Where are the **programs**/**scripts** that generate these messages? I can only find `include` files in the installed Tesseract directory... Where are the files that contain these error messages strings if the image was not found, etc...?

Also, where are the **scripts**/**programs** that perform **image** **pre-processing** (such as **segmentation**, **binarization**, **noise removal**, etc...) before Tesseract actually does the OCR on the image?

*Context/Background*

We are planning to improve (rather customize) Tesseract for our needs (for example recognizing products' serial numbers and vehicle number plates) but obviously **first** we need to know what kind of **filtering** and **thresholding** Tesseract does by default.

I understand Tesseract performs various image-processing operations internally (using the Leptonica library) before doing the actual OCR. For example, I understand Tesseract does Binarization and Segmentation and Noise Removal internally, as well as having a default segmentation method. Is this right? **Which script(s)** contain these methods, so that I can see in what order these internal image-processing operations are carried out before doing the actual OCR?

The github download has a lot of directories and code, so I would really appreciate someone pointing us in the right direction -- where we should look to see the standard parameters and image-processing operations that Tesseract does before doing the actual OCR. We can only find `.h` header files...

Thanks,